# Where are service saved?

Tags: 8

Where are services saved?
With Drush cr they are read, but I do not understand where they are saved
(In non-database I find them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are stored in the `{cache_container}` table of the database. The services themselves are declared in `[MODULENAME].services.yml`.